# Schedule a Jenkins job everyday at 8:30 AM except on Friday

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that runs every day at 8:30 AM.

I want the job not to run on Fridays. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dow` (day of week) to achieve it:

```
30 8 * * 0-4,6 your_command

# 0=Sunday 6=Saturday
```

Comment: AFAIK, ranges are supported too: `30 8 * * 0-6`

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not have this solution before.